# 関数内のローカル変数の値を、ネストした関数から変更する

Tags: python, python3

`f()`で定義したローカル変数`b`の値を、ネスト関数`g()`から変更するにはどうすれば良いのでしょうか。
`global a, b`ではうまくいかず、さりとて代案も思いつきませんでした。

```
a = "global!!"

def f():
    global a
    print(a)
    b = "local 1"

    def g():
        global a
        print(a)
        print(b) # local variable 'b' referenced before assignment
        b = "local 2"
        print(b)

    g()
    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ネストした関数からは参照はできても変更はできません。
最初に書くとネストした関数にローカルな変数になってしまいます。
（エラーメッセージは「代入される前に参照されている」ということでローカル変数として扱われている）

代案としては参照タイプを使うことです。
例えば
`b = ["local 1"]`
のようにリストにすることで、
ネストした関数からも
`b[0] = "local 2"`
で変更できます。
（`b`自体は変更できませんがこれで十分かと思います）

Comment: Python 3 であれば、 `global` の代わりに `nonlocal` を使うと外側のスコープが参照できたりしますね。

Comment: @menew  そうですね。私は知りませんでした（一つ賢くなったピロン）。 なので、是非別に回答として投稿ください。

Answer (score 1):

[`nonlocal` 文](http://docs.python.jp/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=nonlocal#the-nonlocal-statement) が Python3 で追加されました。
`nonlocal` に指定すると、外のスコープを内側から順に探索して、最初に見付かった変数を参照する事になります。
ただし、グローバルスコープは探索範囲に含まれません。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def f():
    b = "local 1"
    print(b)
    # 出力 -> local 1

    def g():
        # 外側の変数 b を参照
        nonlocal b
        b = "local 2"
        print(b)
        # 出力 -> local 2

    g()

    # 変更されている
    print(b)
    # 出力 -> local 2

f()
```